# How can I add data to the data table on the homepage from the add account page with Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have just started learning Flutter. I am developing an application. I would like to ask you for help on a topic in Flutter. This topic is also related to my application. Let me give you a brief summary of the subject I will ask for help. Now in my application there are 2 separate pages called accounts and add account. After the user enters the data on the add account page, after pressing the save button, I want the user to save the data he entered to the database and show it in the DataTable on the accounts homepage. But I researched this a lot, but I could not find a similar example on the internet. Can you help me with this?

I have searched the internet and tried what is written but I did not get any results. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a button that once the user clicks the button, you store the data the user has entered locally on the device using [Flutter secure storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) here, and then on the next page, retrieve the data stored and display it.

You can also make use of other storage packages or DB tools like [Hive Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) or [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).
Once you can store data with any of these packages, you can go ahead and fetch the data in the next page and display it.

Answer (score -1):

It would be nice to see what you have tried before answering this question, but I sounds like you should look for the 'provider' or BLoC pattern. Both will solve your problem.